# Python Lists Itertools and For Loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, python-itertools

I have 2 lists of the same size.

```
list1 = [start1,start2,start3, start4]
list2 = [end1, end2, end3, end4]
```

`startn` in `list1` corresponds to `endn` in `list2`.

I want to use both the lists in a single `for` loop for further calculations.
Problem being: I want to use a combination of 2 elements from each list in the `for` loop. For example:
I want to extract `start1`, `start3` from `list1` and `end1`, `end3` from `list2` and use these 4 values in a `for` loop.

For a single list, to extract a combination of 2 elements, I know it's the following code:

```
import itertools
for a, b in itertools.combinations(mylist, 2):
```

But how do I extract 2 values from `list1` and the same corresponding values from `list2` and use in a `for` loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `zip` the two lists and then use `combination` to pull out the values:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list2 = [1,2,3,4]

from itertools import combinations
for x1, x2 in combinations(zip(list1, list2), 2):
    print(x1, x2)

#(('a', 1), ('b', 2))
#(('a', 1), ('c', 3))
#(('a', 1), ('d', 4))
#(('b', 2), ('c', 3))
#(('b', 2), ('d', 4))
#(('c', 3), ('d', 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more Pythonic way but try this:

```
from itertools import combinations

for i, j in combinations(range(4), 2):
    list1_1, list1_2, list2_1, list2_2 = list1[i], list1[j], list2[i], list2[j]
```

Edit: on second thoughts this is the Pythonic way. I see other people have the same idea though.

```
for (list1_1, list1_2), (list2_1, list2_2) in combinations(zip(list1, list2), 2):
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) to combine the start and end lists together into a bunch of tuples: (s1, e1), (s2, e2), etc. Then do combinations of that:

```
import itertools

starts = 'start1 start2 start3 start4'.split()
ends   = 'end1 end2 end3 end4'.split()

se_pairs = zip(starts, ends)

for a,b in itertools.combinations(se_pairs, 2):
    a_start, a_end = a
    b_start, b_end = b

    print("a: (", a_start, ",", a_end, ")", "b: (", b_start, ",", b_end, ")")
```